When is the right time to inquire about the status of my manuscript after second round of revisions?
After resubmitting my manuscript following revisions for the second time, when should I contact the journal? Here is a timeline of the process thus far:

First submission: March 2023
Request for major revisions: June 2023
Resubmission after revisions: August 2023
The manuscript then underwent a second round of review.
Email regarding the status of the manuscript: January 2024
Request for minor revisions: February 2024
Resubmission after revisions: February 2024
Current manuscript status: With editor

I'm uncertain about when to inquire about the status of my paper. I realise this might seem hasty, but as I'm pursuing my PhD by publication and planning to defend next year, I need my papers published or at least accepted before then. I don't mind if the editor rejects it, but given how lengthy the review/publication process can be, it would be helpful to know sooner so I can submit my paper to another journal.

What is the usual time-frame for papers in your field?  How long is the paper?   What your describes seems very fast for a 60-page pure-math paper, a bit slow for a five-page physics paper.

I think you can wait and I also think you will hear soon-ish if it is "with editor" after minor revisions. The history suggests acceptance. You also have about a year and the paper has, I assume, been improved.
Don't give up on other possible submissions of related work, however, so that you have some backup.
But if it has been two months since your last communication you could make a polite request for a status update. But Feb-April could be just one month and a bit depending on dates.
Note also that a request for status update isn't going to speed the process and withdrawal will certainly slow it.

Thank you for your response! Yes, the paper has significantly improved. It's been one month since I resubmitted. I'll wait another month or so.
